# Is there an agreed upon number of names for Hashem or is there no clear answer?

Tags: names, shemos-sacred-names, divine-names

I've read different sources which give different answers for how many names Hashem has.

- I have read sources which define the **7 holy names** which cannot be erased once written.
- I have read sources which cite **10 divine names**.
- I have read Kabbalistic sources which cite **72 names**.

Is there an agreed upon "standard" with regards to Hashem's names or is it one of those topics which lends itself to subjectivity? Meaning we can all find a reference which we consider a "name" in the sense the narrative uses language which describes Hashem's characteristics and such.

Comment: I recall reading something years ago that posited that every combination of Hebrew letters is a name of Hashem.

Comment: According to kabbalistic sources, the entire Torah is made up of names of Hashem.